# wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk Network Disconnect Unrecoverable

Tags: ubuntu-core, mir, webkit

I am using wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk on Ubuntu Core 22 on a raspberry pi 3b like the following:

```
snap set wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk url=https://www.mysite.com
```

My use case is a digital dashboard that loads a remote site with metrics.  All other orchestration is handled by the remote web app. Having everything else managed by the remote web app works well for many of my other needs.

Everything is working great till there is a network disruption. Then I get a network error on screen like:

```
Page Load Error - Error resolving "www.mysite.com" Temporary Failure In Name Resolution
```

Because this use case does not have a keyboard or mouse connected.  I need a way to have the system try to self recover after a period (i.e. every 30 seconds) and keep trying till the network is available again.

The simplest solution I can think of is to add

```
setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();    
}, 30000);
```

into a script on the error page.  Is it a page that is part of cog?  How would I add that? What other simple solutions should I consider.

I am completely OK with the error screen showing periodically, I just need it to make attempt to self correct before manual intervention (in the form of reboot or plug mouse in) is needed.

Comment: Assuming wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk supports cache, and you control the webapp, have you considered another webdev solution instead of a Ubuntu solution? You could modernize your webapp so it uses ServiceWorker so that the URL will still load when you're offline. Then with AJAX (React/Angular/jQuery/etc.) and your setTimeout, you could try only replacing the current page after successfully loading the data for the next page

Comment: @DanielT you are correct that will work (and I've done that before). I am looking for the simplest solution and trying to see if something like the 3 lines of JS above is feasible before I embark on more complex solutions.